# What type has a spreadsheet checkbox in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, variable-types

I have the following code which is supposed to add a checkbox for every row in a listobject next to it. I want to develop an approval tool, which loads data from a data base and loads it into the listobject. After that i can approve or disapprove the data with the checkbox and save the changes. Since the listobject will have changeing length the checkboxes will need to be added and removed by code.

so here the code:

```
Sub Approval()
Dim i As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim CBcollection As Collection
Dim CB As msforms.CheckBox ' THIS IS WRONG
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim L As Double, T As Double, H As Double, W As Double
Dim rng As Range

Set sht = Tabelle1
Set tbl = sht.ListObjects("ApprovalTBL")
Set rng = tbl.Range(2, 1).Offset(0, -1)
      W = 10
      H = 10
      L = rng.Left + rng.Width / 2 - W / 2
      T = rng.Top + rng.Height / 2 - H / 2

For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
      Set CB = sht.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=L, Top:=T, Width:=W, Height:=H) 
'the line before will give me an error 13 type missmatch
      CBcollection.Add (CB)
      Set rng = rng.Offset(-1, 0)
      T = rng.Top + rng.Height / 2 - H / 2
Next i

End Sub
```

Now the question:

What type has Checkbox in a normal spreadsheet?

I always use "Option Explicit" and I will always dim my variables to the right type and I do not want to use variant types.

Comment: Form Controls or ActiveX Controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *form control* checkbox would be a `Shape`, but that's not what you have here.

Adding an ActiveX checkbox on a worksheet adds a reference to the `MSForms` type library (just like adding a `UserForm` to your VBA project).

The checkbox is indeed a `MSForms.Checkbox` instance, but to live on a worksheet it's *embedded* in an `OLEObject`, a type that lives in the `Excel` type library.

So to get the `MSForms.Checkbox` you need to retrieve the `OLEObject.Object` reference:

```
Dim ctrl As Excel.OLEObject
Set ctrl = sht.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=L, Top:=T, Width:=W, Height:=H) 

Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Set chkBox = ctrl.Object
```

Comment: Your solution works, I just got another problem ::error 91 object or with variable not defined, when trying to add the CheckBox to my collection. Any idea what could be wrong there?

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda looking at your `CBcollection.Add` call, you have extraneous parentheses around the object reference, which to VBA means "evaluate this expression as a value, *and pass the result `ByVal`*" - which is not a good idea when dealing with an object reference (evaluating it as a value isn't likely to end well). Remove the extraneous parentheses, you'll fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's just `Checkbox` - you dont need to qualify it with anything.

If it's on your spreadsheet tho, that's probably an ActiveX checkbox which is defined as `Object`

Comment: It's not... the embedded control is an `OLEObject`, and `Checkbox` *is* defined in the `MSForms` type library, qualified or not.

Answer (score 0):

`OLEObjects.Add` returns `OLEObject`, so declare your variable like this:

```
Dim CB As OLEObject
```

Comment: if I use OLEObject it will not give me the error 13 type missmatch but gives me error 438: object doesn't support property or method.. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda see my answer

Comment: Ah, beat me to it!